# javascript document.getElementById is not working inside while loop

Tags: javascript

please help me, I am stuck. When I write it as

```
document.write(parseInt(n1) + ",")
```

It works, but when i write it as

```
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = parseInt(n1) + ",";
```

It does not work.

Instead of showing for example:
1,3,5,7,9,...

it only shows one number, like:
9,

Here's my code:

```
Maximum Range:<input type="number" id="maximum"> <br><br>

number 1: <input type="number" id="number1"> <br>
increment 1: <input type="number" id="increment1">

<br><br>



<button onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button> <hr>

<strong>Results:</strong>
<p id="result1"></p>

<script>
    function calculate() {
        let n1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
        let i1 = document.getElementById("increment1").value;
        let max = document.getElementById("maximum").value;
        while (parseInt(n1) <= parseInt(max)) {
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = parseInt(n1) + ",";
            n1 = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(i1);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `innerHTML +=` ?

Comment: Wow I did not see it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

change this line
`document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = parseInt(n1) + ",";`

to this

`document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML += parseInt(n1) + ",";`

as mentioned in comments..